# Extbase Variable Dump nodes not expandable

Tags: debugging, typo3, fluid, typo3-9.x

With an fresh composer TYPO3 9.5.9 installation debugging fluid templates it is not possible to expand array tree nodes in the "Extbase Variable Dump".

I can see the first levels data, but clicking on the plus symbol to expand a array node nothing happens.

Any hint on solving this issue will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Jan

Answer (score 0):

Check if there are Javascript errors in the the frontend which are blocking the functionality.

Debuggung JS in Chrome dev tools:
[image: Debuggung JS in Chrome dev tools]

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is any (maybe invisible) DOM element in front of the Debug which has a higher z-index preventing you from clicking the icons.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome dev tools do not report any JS problems.

I will activate a minimal page template to exclude potential side effects html structure or of the libraries included in the current page template.

I'm about to set up a new virtual machine on my home computer to simply exclude the work environment as a source of error.

Thank you for your help, I will report.

Jan

Answer (score 0):

coming back late: the expand button event handler from the output debug was overwritten by another js lib, commenting that (unneccesary) lib out in dev mode solved the problem.

strophi

Answer (score 0):

It could be a css problem. In my case there was a:

```
input[type=checkbox] { display:none; } in my css.
```

I solved it by changing the css to:

```
.main-content input[type=checkbox] { display:none; }
```